# YAML error while using Docker-Composure command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

*I am a newbie in the docker world and while doing some tutorials I encountered the following error:*

```
yaml: line 1: did not find expected key
```

This is my .YAML file:

```html
version: '3'
  services:
    mongodb:
      image: mongo
      ports:
        -27017:27017
      environment:
        - MONGO-INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
        - MONGO-INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    mongo-express:
      image: mongo-express
      ports:
        -8080:8081
      environment:
        -ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
        -ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
        -ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
```

I tried to search if there is a problem with the compatibility of the docker-compose & docker-engine but even though I tried to put other versions like `2/2.1/2.2/2.3/3/3.8` in the `".YAML"` file I still get the same error message.

```
Docker Compose version v2.2.1 <br>
Docker Engine v20.10.11
```

Tried to look up some solutions but I was not able to find anything.

Comment: After `version: 3`, we must not indent, i.e. `services` should be on the same indentation-level as `version: 3`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Turing85,

I tried to delete the indent of `services` in order to be on the same indent as `version` and now I get the following message:

`services.mongo-express.environment must be a mapping`

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is incorrect and some other spacing/syntax is also incorrect.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO-INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO-INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
```